# How different echo ({!! ... !!} and {{...}}) in laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

In laravel 5.3, sometimes I use this : `{!! ... !!}`, sometimes I use this : `{{ ... }}`

When I use it, it goes well

I want to ask, what is the difference of both?

Comment: in the first one, with the "bang bang"(yep, that's what its called, lol), you can do interpolation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Laravel 5.3 doc

```
Displaying Unescaped Data

By default, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

Hello, {!! $name !!}.
```